# Does mapbox gl support expressions in setPaintProperty?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

The below expression is working fine in `map.addLayer()`

```
"paint": {
        "circle-radius":10,
        'circle-color': [
                'match',
                ['get', 'idx'],
                0, 'red',
                1, 'green',
                2, 'blue',
                3, 'black',
                /* other */ 'pink'

            ]
        }
```

Then I tryed to apply the same in `map.setPaintProperty()`

```
map.setPaintProperty("points","circle-color",
                     ['match',
    ['get','idx'],
    0,"black",
    1,"blue",
    2,"green",
    3,"red"
    ] );
```

But that throws the error:

> Error: layers.points.paint.circle-color: Expected an even number of arguments.

So my question is: Does mapbox gl support expressions in setPaintProperty?

Comment: You forgot the default value.